# How to render Draco compressed GLB file in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an mobile app using react native to render Draco compressed GLB file. I have tried to render GLB file using @react-three/fiber package and I was able to render GLB file without compression. But not able to render compressed one. Please help me to decompress Draco GLB file and render it in react native.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can not use meshopt or DRACO for compression for models on react native. Here is a thread explaining the issue:

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/2992

Answer (score 0):

Try using ktx2 loader for glb model compression

[Here's a thread which might be useful for you](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/2307)